# Conditional Columns and Delimited Fields

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, powerquery, m

I receive a daily export of data every day I load into my excel sheet via Power Query. The table of data I can't control is:

**tblExport**

| Name | Company | States |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | ABC | AK,AL,GA,WA |
| John Smith | ACME | AK,GA,FL,WA |

I need to replace those State Abbreviations with a technology string of information for this question I'll use "Full State Name" as a substitute. So basically it checks the COMPANY field against another table as the "technology Strings" will be different for each Company per State.

So far so good, or so I thought. Then I split delimiters of tblExport.States BY "," which then I get

| Name | Company | States.1 | States.2 | States.3 | States.4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | ABC | AK | AL | GA | WA |
| John Smith | ACME | AK | GA | FL | WA |

Now we reference that table that contains the Company, State, FullStateNames

**tblStateNames**

| COMPANY | Abbr | State Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | AL | AlabamaABC |
| ABC | AK | AlaskaABC |
| ACME | AK | AlaskaACME |
| ACME | GA | GeorgiaACME |
| ABC | FL | FloridaABC |
| ABC | WA | WashingtonABC |
| ACME | WA | WashingtonACME |

```
        ST01 = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1", {"States.1", "Company"}, 
        tblStateNames, {"Abbr", "Company"}, "tblStateNames", 
        JoinKind.LeftOuter),
        ExpST01 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ST01, "tblStateNames", {"State 
        Name"}, {"tblStateNames.State Name"}),
```

Which works great until I meet a condition such as Company ABC has GA in the TblExport.States, but they do not qualify for GA. So when it joins the query tblStateNames and ABC doesn't match for GA it returns a null value.

So my column output is

| Name | Company | ST01 | ST02 | ST03 | ST04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | ABC | AlaskaABC | AlabamaABC | *null* | WashingtonABC |
| John Smith | ACME | AlaskaACME | GeorgiaACME | FloridaACME | WashingtonACME |

A couple things about this. The original TblExport is a daily intake and the people range for their states, some will have ZERO and the rest can be anywhere from 1 to 40 states. The challenge and why this is semi the issue is because I can't have any gaps in the columns. So while ST03 displays null as it should I rather have it fill ST04 into the ST03 column.

| Name | Company | ST01 | ST02 | ST03 | ST04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | ABC | AlaskaABC | *null* | *null* | WashingtonABC |
| John Smith | ACME | AlaskaACME | GeorgiaACME | FloridaACME | WashingtonACME |

Now after the fact I could do a conditional IF ST02 is not equal <> null then ST02 else ST03.  However in this example that null simply moves from ST03 to ST02. However, this only moves the next one down a column, so a double null will still lead to an issue.

In my *very new to PQ* head, I think I somehow need to validate the states in the original delimited field before doing the query lookup?

I know I've probably overly complicated things and masking the actual code for internal only reasons, takes a bit longer for me to try to explain. :)

I appreciate any input, when responding, try to keep in mind my experience level.
**Experience Level:** *I'm a Highly Functioning Idiot*.

Patrick

Comment: First, why make a table that combines company name and full state if you could just have a full state table by itself and then add the company name afterwards. Then you would never not have a full state for any potential company name.  Assuming that does not apply for some reason, what do you want to do if the furthest right column is a null ? What do you then copy sideways to fill in, do they remain Nulls ?

Comment: Right. Good question @horseyride It could be my inherit flawed original design. However this table holds a few things. 

Company Name  | State Abbr  | Server Address

Since there are MULTIPLE companies and those Companies may or may not exist in a state. If they do then the server address is unique to the company and the state. 

ACME Company for Alaska server would be WPS023223.something.domain
ABC Company for Alaska server would be WHS21111.something.domain

So Alaska exists more than once. As I said it could be the inherit flawed design of what I have.

Comment: EDIT: 
So what you are suggesting is make a TABLE for Each Company with 
STATE | SERVER ADDRESS

Since the original data I get in from the end user "they could mistakenly select the wrong states" so I want to validate that the States in the Delimited Original table are VALID for that company. Then remove the ones that are not. Then perform the Query Lookups for STATE and return Server Address (in this case FULL State Name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, here is one way to do it:

- Read in the two tables
- split the Export table state abbreviations into **ROWS**
- Join with the StateName Table
- Group by Name and Company
- Extract a delimited list of the state names from each subtable
- Expand that list

*Please read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand what is going on*

```
let

//Read in the two tables
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblStateNames"]}[Content],
    tblStateNames = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblExport"]}[Content],
    tblExport = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source2), each {_, type text})),

//split the States column by comma into Rows
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(tblExport, {
        {"States", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
            let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "States"),

//join with the States Names
    joined = Table.Join(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"States","Company"},tblStateNames,{"Abbr","COMPANY"}, JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(joined,{"States", "COMPANY", "Abbr"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Name","Company"}, {
        {"States", each Text.Combine([State Name],";"),type text}}),

//split with no column Count option
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "States", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv))
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was an amazing and quick solve. I have so much to learn!